# Less loop mixin for incremental clases

Tags: html, css, less

I want to create a mixin in less 1.5 that will replace this current css.

```
    .classx1{margin:10px;}
    .classx2{margin:20px;}
    .classx3{margin:30px;}
    .classx4{margin:40px;}
    .classx5{margin:50px;}
     ...
    .classx30{margin:300px;}
```

Already tried this but is not working:

```
@iterations: 30;
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    classx@{index} {
        margin: -@index px;
    }
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (0) {}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

and in html I added the class:

```
<div class="container classx20">CONTENT</div>
```

The div with classes container and classx20 should have `margin: 200px`

So what is not ok ?
ty.

Comment: Try `(~".classx@{index}") {`

Comment: @BeatAlex from 1.4 version this "(~".classx@{index}")" is not working and was changed in  "classx@{index}" from what I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes in your code

1) Missing dot before `classx`

2) Space between margin value and `px`

```
classx@{index} {
        margin: -@index px;
}
```

So CSS result looks like this:

```
classx30 {
  margin: -30 px;
}
classx29 {
  margin: -29 px;
}
classx28 {
  margin: -28 px;
}
...
```

---

**The right way with escaping string:**

```
@iterations: 30;
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
  .classx@{index} {
    margin: ~"@{index}px";
  }
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (0) {}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tvqGo)

[More info on lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation)

Comment: :)) nice but on my project still is not working, however this is the correct answer so I should check what is wrong in my project. I am using bootstrap but I don't think this has any interference. ty

Answer (score 3):

Your calculations make no sense for what you say the output is supposed to be. This is what will give the output you desire:

```
@iterations: 30;
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    .classx@{index} { //Added dot here to make it a class
        margin: unit(@index * 10, px); //KEY CHANGE HERE
    }
    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (0) {}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

If `.classx20` is supposed to be `margin: 200px` then you need to be multiply the index by `10`, not trying to negate it with a negative value.